# Is it possible to disable first row from clicking on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got event `CellMouseClick` that is editing the selected Row, but I have filter also so , when I click on the first row new dialog is showing with the edit `datagrid`.Is it possible to disable only first row click in `DataGridView`,tried that but not working:

```
 advancedDataGridView.Rows[0].ReadOnly=true;
```

Comment: It is certainly possible to make it *seem like* it is disabled.  Particularly if this is a subclassed control.

Comment: In cell mouse click handler check for row index, if it is row 0 then return.

Comment: ... or if it's greater than zero, show the dialog.